# Cannot read properties of null in Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Vue3 with Nuxt3 ([universal rendering](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#universal-rendering)) and here is code for my page:

```html
<!-- /pages/search.vue -->
<script setup>

const route = useRoute();

const {pending, data} = await useLazyFetch(
    "api/car-models"
    + `?start-date=${route.query.startDate}`
    + `&end-date=${route.query.endDate}`,
);

</script>
<template>
        <div v-if="pending">
            Loading...
        </div>
        <div v-else-if="data.carModels.length === 0">
            Sorry, no cars available for the selected dates and location.
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <ul>
                <li v-for="car in data.carModels">
                    <CarCard :car="car"/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</template>
```

it works fine, and `CarCard`s are showing when i navigate to page. But when i hit refresh, I get

```
500
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'carModels')
at ...
```

Why I get this error/exception only after reload and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: carModels is not defined in data (yet), so use `v-else-if="!data.carModels || data.carModels.length === 0"`

Comment: Then what is the purpose of `pending` from Nuxt's useLazyFetch?

Comment: nested properties should always be checked before using anyway, rtm: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch it says If you have not fetched data on the server (for example, with server: false), then the data will not be fetched until hydration completes. This means even if you await useFetch on client-side, data will remain null within <script setup>. and also mentioned in comments https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-lazy-fetch posts might start out null, you won't have access
  // to its contents immediately, but you can watch it.

Comment: when i add this check (i use `!data || ...` because when i used `!data.carModels || ...` i got same 500 error agan)  only "Sorry, no cars available..." text is rendered after refresh. Do you know how can I watch it or something, in order to show the actual cars from my api?

Comment: I tried using `reactive()` and update it in watcher but result is the same

Comment: Is your app in SSR?

Comment: Yes, I'll add it in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from the docs:

```html
<template>
  <!-- you will need to handle a loading state -->
  <div v-if="pending">
    Loading ...
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <div v-for="post in posts">
      <!-- do something -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const { pending, data: posts } = await useLazyFetch('/api/posts')
watch(posts, (newPosts) => {
  // Because posts might start out null, you will not have access
  // to its contents immediately, but you can watch it.
})
</script>
```

The reason you get an error is because at first the result is `null`. You could just write `v-else-if="data?.carModels.length === 0"` with the question mark to automatically check for null, but you should still have to watch your data to update the result to show.

Docs: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#uselazyfetch

Comment: Sorry if it's a basic question, but I'm new to Vue/Nuxt. How can I watch my data to update template when it has value? What should i put in the watch function?

Comment: In the watch function you simply assign the "newPosts" or whatever you call your new data to a ref you define in the script section, then you show that data in the template. I suggest taking a look at the watch documentation to understand better what's going on